# Initialize this.variable_name in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a javaScript function with the name foo. x is a global variable that we increase in this function. then I put this.x = x and return function. then I defined a variable bar = new new foo(). after running this code, the value of bar.x is undefined. but why?

```
var x=0;
function foo(){
  x++;
  this.x = x;
  return foo;
}
var bar = new new new foo;
console.log(bar.x);
```

Comment: Putting aside, that you are returning `foo` from the the construtor instead of `this` and forgetting the `()` when calling the constructor (ie `new foo` instead of `new foo()`): What do you think you would acomplish with `new new new foo()` (ie 3 times `new`)

Comment: @derpirscher it is not mandatory to append `()` when using the `new` operator on a constructor.

Comment: I'm curious what's a common use case of new new new foo? Then what will be the expected value of new new new new new new new new foo? What's the entire purpose of this question? And this is not your function, the same function been explained elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of your code is a direct result of the nature of JS Constructors and the `new` operator. Also, it is behaving as expected. I assume, however that your question is merely theoretical because I don't really see a valid use case for chaining multiple `new` operators.

In your code, `foo` is a Constructor, and its only purpose is to specify the type of instance that should be created. In other words, its form/structure.

When you use the `new` operator on a Constructor, it creates a plain blank object and links to it the Constructor function (`instance.constructor`), then it assigns this newly created object to the `this` context of the function and runs it.

If the function returns an object, then `new` returns that object too! If not, then `new` automatically returns that first created object (`this`).

In your case, you are returning a reference to your own Constructor. That is an object. So, `new foo;` is always returning a constructor. That is why you are allowed to chain multiple `new` operators, which is not possible when using a standard constructor.

To obtain the value of `x`, you must return `this` inside your constructor or not return an object at all.

Hope this clarifies the inner mechanics of it.

Oh! And despite general knowledge, the use of `()` when using `new` operator is not necessary.

Finally, to close the ring, please see the following snipped, using your code:

```js
let x = 0;

function Foo(c){
  x++;
  
  this.x = x;
  
  return c ? this : Foo;
}

new new new new new new new new new Foo;

const bar = new Foo(1);

console.log(bar.x); // EXPECTED TO PRINT 10.
```

Comment: While it might not be mandatory to use `()` with a parameterless constructor, it's definitely good style and most linters per default give a warning, when you skip them.

Comment: @derpirscher I always use `()`, but I think the whole point of this question was to push the limits of JS Constructors.